# Returning errors back to development team from deployed iOS application

Tags: ios, error-handling

Long time ASP.Net developer, first time iOS app developer here. I am writing an iPhone app at present and I would like to know how best to notify myself when the app experiences a fault out in deployment.

What do people do currently? Do you return the error codes back to a server periodically? Does Apple have a special tool that I am yet to hear about?

with ASP.Net it is relatively easy as it is server based technology, thus most errors are experienced on the server and the server can record this information. With iOS applications the error is experienced on the device and I am concerned that I may end up with an error that repeatedly occurs but my users either do not tell me about or I cannot reproduce.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what kind of errors you're talking about...

Exceptions are automatically reported back by Apple. But, they don't give all exceptions back and there is a lag. There are several 3rd party services which you can use where you add their framework and it will detect the exception and send it back to their server for you to analyse.

For non-exception errors there is nothing standard. I would suggest adding analytics to your app and using part of the analytics to track these occurrences.

Comment: Ah! So exceptions (the sort of thing that would cause the application to crash out) are automatically reported by Apple. That is exactly what I was after. Is this done through email or through the developer account work area?

Comment: Via iTunesConnect, when looking at the details for a particular version of an app.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the crashes can be recorded using crashlytics framework or using hockey app so that you will get notified and also you can integrate Google Analytics into your iOS application to find out the number of crashes and in particular in which screen they are occurred.